# Jupyter: trick to run next cell even if previous cell fails

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, alerts

I want to send alerts if a long running cell fails, but I don't want to try/except because then I will send needless messages when I am looking at the error. Is there a way to do this?

Desired workflow:

1) run `status=train()` cell

2) see no error in first 15 seconds

3) execute next cell `send_alert('done or error')` that will execute regardless of the outcome of cell 1.

4) Go do something else

Here is a one cell solution that is annoying to code every time:

```
try:
    start = time.time()
    train(...)
except Exception as e:
    pass
end = time.time()
if end - start > 60: send_alert('done')
```

Comment: You can use `nbconvert` (see https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#execute-and-save-all-errors) to get this from the CLI, but it looks like you want to interactively do this? 

This looks like you want a decorator, but for a cell: would writing a custom line/cell magic work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one solution, with a pretty small but extensible custom iPython magic.

You can keep it in a file named `magics.py` somewhere, or have a pip-installable package. I used something pip-installable:

```
.
├── magics
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── executor.py
└── setup.py
```

```py
# magics/executor.py

import time
from IPython.core.magic import Magics, magics_class, cell_magic

@magics_class
class Exceptor(Magics):

    @cell_magic
    def exceptor(self, line, cell):
        timeout = 2
        try:
            start = time.time()
            self.shell.ex(cell)
        except:
            if time.time() - start > timeout:
                print("Slow fail!")
        else:
            if time.time() - start > timeout:
                print("done")
```

```py
# magics/__init__.py

from .exceptor import Exceptor

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.register_magics(Exceptor)
```

Here is an example of using this. Notice that `%load_ext magics` takes the name of the package, and then gives you the cell magic named `%exceptor`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Used flit to make a pypi package.