# Is it possible to continue execution after error in Jupyter?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a notebook that I'm using to learn, and I'd like to "keep" the errors in there as instructions to myself on what not to do. Here's a basic example:

```
# (1b) Rename with a list of data
df['cost_bad'] = [1,2] # <-- this will error, since the length of the List/Series must match the numRows
df['cost_good'] = ...
```

However, this will (obviously) error on the first python statement and never run to the second one. Is there a way to set the notebook to execute all statements, even if a previous on errors? I know I can do something like:

```
try:
    df['cost_bad'] = [1,2] # <-- this will error, since the length of the List/Series must match the numRows
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

But I was wondering if I could do this **without** the `try/except` and just continue execution.

Comment: Put the exact exception (e.g. `excet ValueError as e: print(e)`)

Comment: If you want the stack trace, you can use `traceback.print_exc()` in your exception handler: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney no I'm saying I don't want to catch it at all. Just for the python statements to run one after another...but assuming that isn't possible?

Comment: @Samwise it's about the jupyter execution not really the python try/except that I'm asking about.

Comment: Maybe [How to automatically execute next cell even if an error occurs in the current cell in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402480/how-to-automatically-execute-next-cell-even-if-an-error-occurs-in-the-current-ce), but Jupyter won't execute a cell if there is a error, which is why you should use `try except continue.`

Comment: [Jupyter: trick to run next cell even if previous cell fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57364510/jupyter-trick-to-run-next-cell-even-if-previous-cell-fails), but it won't continue running things in that cell.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney oh got it, yes that's what I was curious about -- thanks for those links.